# Flutter - How do I run a method after the Slider interaction has ended?

Tags: dart, slider, flutter

I'm currently learning Flutter and I'm having some trouble showing a Snackbar after the interaction with the slider has ended (in other words, the final value was set when the user lifts their finger off the slider). I can't call my `_showSnackBar()` method in `onChange` because the snackbar is created and shown many times, one after the other.

Is there something I can do to call a method only after the interaction has finished? I was thinking of making a pull request and add something like `onInteractionEnded` callback property, but I would like to find out of there is another way first.

Here is my code for reference.

```
class _MySliderState extends State<MySlider> {

  int _value = 2;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Slider(
      min: 0.0,
      max: 4.0,
      divisions: 4,
      value: (_value * 1.0),
      onChanged: (double value) {
          setState(() {
            _value = value ~/ 1;
          });
          _showSnackBar();
      },
    );
  }

  void _showSnackBar() {
    var snackbar = SnackBar(content: const Text('Slider value changed'));
    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackbar);
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`onChangeStart` and `onChangeEnd` was added to `Slider` very recently

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/17298

The change should available in master already.

Comment: Ah, awesome thanks :) I'm currently on the beta builds, which is why I didn't see it. I was hoping that I could've contributed something to Flutter. :P But glad someone added it.